# execvp() wont load file: "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, process, fork, execvp

I wrote 2 programs.
The first one gets 2 strings through argv and prints the program process id and the smallest string (by dictionary order).

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int cmp;
    if (argc != 3){
        perror("Wrong arguments");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    printf("my ID: %d\n",getpid());
    cmp = strcmp(argv[1],argv[2]);
    if (cmp < 0)
        puts(argv[1]);

    else if (cmp > 0)
        puts(argv[2]);

    else puts(argv[1]);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have compiled the code via terminal with:

```
gcc -Wall my_cmp.c -o my_cmp
```

The second program creates a child process and performs `execvp()` with `my_cmp` sending "abc" "de".

```
void do_sun(char **argv);

int main() {
    pid_t status;
    char *args[] = { "my_cmp", "abc","de", NULL };

    status = fork();

    if (status < 0){
        perror("Cannot fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (status == 0){
        char *args[] = { "my_cmp", "abc","de", NULL };
        do_sun(args);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (status > 0){
        wait(&status);
        if (execvp(args[0],args) != 0 )
            perror("error");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void do_sun(char **args){
    if (execvp(args[0],args) == -1 )
                perror("error");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run the program I am getting this message:

```
error: No such file or directory
error: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to switch directory to the my_cmp file with no success.

Comment: Try `./my_cmp` instead of `my_cmp`.

Comment: such a silly mistake:O  thank you
problem solved

Comment: Accepting the answer is better than editing the question.  Edit rolled back.

Comment: Note that using `execv()` instead of `execvp()` would avoid the path-search and would simply have executed the program in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some systems it won't search working directory for executable binary files by default.

You should use `./my_cmp` instead of `my_cmp` to have it work on such systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `execvp`, you are saying that the executable will be found "in the path"; that is, in one of the directories listed in `$PATH`. Few directories are on this path, and while it is possible to add `.` to `$PATH`, that's generally regarded to be asecurity vulnerability.

If you want to specify the path to the executable (in which case you can put it in whatever directory you want), use the non-path `execv`.